# Tensorboard - No module named 'tensorflow.python.types'

Tags: tensorboard

I try to use tensorboard but I have meet the error

```
    tensorboard

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
2020-12-28 20:02:32.654421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\Anaconda3\envs\Dacon\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import beholder_plugin_loader
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder.beholder import Beholder
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\beholder.py", line 212, in <module>
    class BeholderHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "c:\users\eavn\anaconda3\envs\dacon\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "C:\Users\Eavn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\model_fn.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.types import core


    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.types'
```

And I use tensorflow-gpu 2.2 & python=3.7.3

```
absl-py                   0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi               20.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
async-generator           1.10                     pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     20.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.12.8            haa95532_0  
cached-property           1.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cachetools                4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37haa95532_0  
cffi                      1.14.4                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
confuse                   1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
htmlmin                   0.1.12                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.10                     pypi_0    pypi
imagehash                 4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 5.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                7.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    2.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
json5                     0.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            6.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab                2.2.9                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
lightgbm                  3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
llvmlite                  0.35.0                   pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
missingno                 0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.5                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
numba                     0.52.0                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1i               h2bbff1b_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 20.8                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas-profiling          2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
phik                      0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.3.3           py37haa95532_0  
prometheus-client         0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2020.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   300                      pypi_0    pypi
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     20.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.6                      pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.23.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                51.0.0           py37haa95532_2  
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0  
tangled-up-in-unicode     0.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-addons         0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu-estimator  2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.1                      pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.55.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
typeguard                 2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.2                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1  
visions                   0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2  
wcwidth                   0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0  
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xgboost                   1.3.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please carefully read ["How-to ask ?" topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rewrite your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try to upgrade the package to the last version and see if it works.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow.
```

And also try to use python 3.8.5 or 3.9.0 instead of 3.7.3. Hope it works.